# Issue with Defining varspecs and odefunc in PyDSTool for a Biological Model Simulation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, simulation, ode

Good afternoon everyone:
I'm trying to simulate a biological model using PyDSTool in Python, focusing on the dynamics of Whi5 and SBF activation in budding yeast cells. I've defined two state variables (whi5 and sbf_active) and a set of parameters for my model. However, I'm encountering difficulties in properly defining the varspecs and odefunc for my ODE system.

Here's the part of the code where I'm experiencing issues:

```
import PyDSTool as dst
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

# Parameters
params = {
    'cln3_conc': 1.0,  # Constant concentration of Cln3
    'sbf_binding_rate': 0.1,  # Rate of SBF binding
    'cell_growth_rate': 0.05  # Cell growth rate
}

# ODEs
def odes(t, y, p):
    whi5, sbf_active = y
    cln3 = p['cln3_conc']

    # Dynamics of Whi5
    dwhi5_dt = -p['cell_growth_rate'] * whi5

    # Dynamics of SBF activation
    dsbf_active_dt = p['sbf_binding_rate'] * cln3 * (1 - sbf_active) - p['sbf_binding_rate'] * whi5 * sbf_active

    return [dwhi5_dt, dsbf_active_dt]

# Initial Conditions and Time domain
y0 = {'whi5': 1.0, 'sbf_active': 0}
tdomain = [0, 100]

# Set up the system
DSargs = dst.args()
DSargs.name = 'yeast_cell_cycle'
DSargs.tdomain = tdomain
DSargs.pars = params
DSargs.varspecs = {'whi5': '-cell_growth_rate * whi5', 
                   'sbf_active': 'sbf_binding_rate * cln3_conc * (1 - sbf_active) - sbf_binding_rate * whi5 * sbf_active'}
DSargs.odefunc = odes
DSargs.ics = y0

# Create the system
system = dst.Generator.Vode_ODEsystem(DSargs)
```

When I try to run the simulation, I encounter the following error:

```
PyDSTool_KeyError: 'Invalid keyword arguments for this class'
```

I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm defining varspecs or odefunc, but I'm not certain. I have checked that PyDSTool is correctly installed and imported.

Question: How should I correctly define varspecs and odefunc in this context to successfully create and run my ODE system in PyDSTool? Are there any specific considerations I'm missing for setting up a biological model like this?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!